# Unsure how to mount usb hard drive on raspberry pi

Tags: mount

My Ubuntu laptop has died, so I have taken the hard disk out and connected it to my raspberry pi running raspbian via usb. I am trying to access my files on the disk.

`sudo parted -l` outputs:

```
Model: ST500LT0 32-1E9142 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32                 boot
 2      538MB   492GB  491GB   ext4
 3      492GB   500GB  8483MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

I want to cd into the 492GB partition. I assume the number 2 indicates it is /dev/sda2; is that correct? I tried `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt` but that gives me

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For the "wrong fs type" you can try to add type ext4, e.g. `sudo mount -t ext4  /dev/sda2 /mnt`

Comment: didn't help - still getting the same error. Is /dev/sda2 correct? I just guessed

Comment: Your entry /dev/sda2 is fine, but can you create a new mount point , e.g. /tmp/old to be sure for empty directory.